# Split string with pattern

Tags: python

I want to split the string into separate list based on the pattern. Let say I have the string look like this

```
string = '1.e4 d6 2.d4 Nf6 3.Nc3 g6 4.Nf3 Bg7 5.Be2 Nbd7 6.O-O O-O 7.e5 dxe5 8.dxe5 Ng4 9.e6 Nde5 10.Qxd8   1-1 1.c2 d6 2.d4 Nf6 3.Nc3 g6 4.Nf3 Bg7 5.Be2 Nbd7 6.O-O O-O 7.e5 dxe5 8.dxe5 Ng4 9.e6 Nde5 10.Qxd8 Rxd8 11.Nxe5 Nxe5  1-0 1.b5 d6 2.d4 Nf6 3.Nc3 g6 4.Nf3 Bg7 5.Be2 Nbd7 6.O-O O-O 7.e5 dxe5 8.dxe5 Ng4 9.e6 Nde5 10.Qxd8 Rxd8 11.Nxe5 Nxe5 12.Nb5  1/2-1/2'
```

The pattern should recognize the `1.` as the start, and end before another `1.`

```
[1.e4 d6 2.d4 Nf6 3.Nc3 g6 4.Nf3 Bg7 5.Be2 Nbd7 6.O-O O-O 7.e5 dxe5 8.dxe5 Ng4 9.e6 Nde5 10.Qxd8   1-1]
[1.c2 d6 2.d4 Nf6 3.Nc3 g6 4.Nf3 Bg7 5.Be2 Nbd7 6.O-O O-O 7.e5 dxe5 8.dxe5 Ng4 9.e6 Nde5 10.Qxd8 Rxd8 11.Nxe5 Nxe5  1-0]
[1.b5 d6 2.d4 Nf6 3.Nc3 g6 4.Nf3 Bg7 5.Be2 Nbd7 6.O-O O-O 7.e5 dxe5 8.dxe5 Ng4 9.e6 Nde5 10.Qxd8 Rxd8 11.Nxe5 Nxe5 12.Nb5  1/2-1/2]
```

I do something like this

```
lists=[]
reg = '^\\1\\.'
for i in string :
  re.match(reg, i)
    lists.extend[i]
```

Comment: `string.split(' 1.')`

Comment: What's going wrong? Any errors? Unexpected output?

Comment: @JohnGordon if I did split, the 1. in the second list is missing. I want to include them also.

Comment: How is the second list missing? Everything should still be found...

Comment: ```['1.e4 d6 2.d4 Nf6 3.Nc3 g6 4.Nf3 Bg7 5.Be2 Nbd7 6.O-O O-O 7.e5 dxe5 8.dxe5 Ng4 9.e6 Nde5 10.Qxd8   1-1',
 'c2 d6 2.d4 Nf6 3.Nc3 g6 4.Nf3 Bg7 5.Be2 Nbd7 6.O-O O-O 7.e5 dxe5 8.dxe5 Ng4 9.e6 Nde5 10.Qxd8 Rxd8 11.Nxe5 Nxe5  1-0',
 'b5 d6 2.d4 Nf6 3.Nc3 g6 4.Nf3 Bg7 5.Be2 Nbd7 6.O-O O-O 7.e5 dxe5 8.dxe5 Ng4 9.e6 Nde5 10.Qxd8 Rxd8 11.Nxe5 Nxe5 12.Nb5  1/2-1/2']```

this is the result if i run the code. maybe because it is splitting by 1. and everytime it find 1. it will take the next value

Comment: Yes, that's true. You can always prepend `" 1."` with a method of your choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `re.findall` here with the pattern `.*?\s+\d+(?:/\d+)?-\d+(?:/\d+)?`:

```py
string = '1.e4 d6 2.d4 Nf6 3.Nc3 g6 4.Nf3 Bg7 5.Be2 Nbd7 6.O-O O-O 7.e5 dxe5 8.dxe5 Ng4 9.e6 Nde5 10.Qxd8   1-1 1.c2 d6 2.d4 Nf6 3.Nc3 g6 4.Nf3 Bg7 5.Be2 Nbd7 6.O-O O-O 7.e5 dxe5 8.dxe5 Ng4 9.e6 Nde5 10.Qxd8 Rxd8 11.Nxe5 Nxe5  1-0 1.b5 d6 2.d4 Nf6 3.Nc3 g6 4.Nf3 Bg7 5.Be2 Nbd7 6.O-O O-O 7.e5 dxe5 8.dxe5 Ng4 9.e6 Nde5 10.Qxd8 Rxd8 11.Nxe5 Nxe5 12.Nb5  1/2-1/2'
parts = re.findall(r'(.*?\s+\d+(?:/\d+)?-\d+(?:/\d+)?)\s*', string)
print(parts)
```

This prints:

```
['1.e4 d6 2.d4 Nf6 3.Nc3 g6 4.Nf3 Bg7 5.Be2 Nbd7 6.O-O O-O 7.e5 dxe5 8.dxe5 Ng4 9.e6 Nde5 10.Qxd8   1-1',
 '1.c2 d6 2.d4 Nf6 3.Nc3 g6 4.Nf3 Bg7 5.Be2 Nbd7 6.O-O O-O 7.e5 dxe5 8.dxe5 Ng4 9.e6 Nde5 10.Qxd8 Rxd8 11.Nxe5 Nxe5  1-0',
 '1.b5 d6 2.d4 Nf6 3.Nc3 g6 4.Nf3 Bg7 5.Be2 Nbd7 6.O-O O-O 7.e5 dxe5 8.dxe5 Ng4 9.e6 Nde5 10.Qxd8 Rxd8 11.Nxe5 Nxe5 12.Nb5  1/2-1/2']
```

Here is a brief explanation of the regex pattern used:

```regex
(                 match and capture
    .*?           all content up to the nearest
    \s+           whitespace
    \d+(?:/\d+)?  followed by e.g. 1 or 1/2
    -             dash
    \d+(?:/\d+)?  another 1 or 1/2
)                 stop capture
\s*               match, but do not capture, optional whitespace
```

Comment: Can you tell me the regex parts please?

Answer (score 0):

```
string = '1.e4 d6 2.d4 Nf6 3.Nc3 g6 4.Nf3 Bg7 5.Be2 Nbd7 6.O-O O-O 7.e5 dxe5 8.dxe5 Ng4 9.e6 Nde5 10.Qxd8   1-1 1.c2 d6 2.d4 Nf6 3.Nc3 g6 4.Nf3 Bg7 5.Be2 Nbd7 6.O-O O-O 7.e5 dxe5 8.dxe5 Ng4 9.e6 Nde5 10.Qxd8 Rxd8 11.Nxe5 Nxe5  1-0 1.b5 d6 2.d4 Nf6 3.Nc3 g6 4.Nf3 Bg7 5.Be2 Nbd7 6.O-O O-O 7.e5 dxe5 8.dxe5 Ng4 9.e6 Nde5 10.Qxd8 Rxd8 11.Nxe5 Nxe5 12.Nb5  1/2-1/2'

print([['1.'+i] for i in (" "+string).split(' 1.')][1:])
```

This works fine too!

Comment: I tried it but it missing the first index of the string, modified the [1:] to be [0:] however it looks like this , the 0 index has another 1. `[['1.1.e4 d6 2.d4 Nf6 3.Nc3 g6 4.Nf3 Bg7 5.Be2 Nbd7 6.O-O O-O 7.e5 dxe5 8.dxe5 Ng4 9.e6 Nde5 10.Qxd8   1-1'],
 ['1.c2 d6 2.d4 Nf6 3.Nc3 g6 4.Nf3 Bg7 5.Be2 Nbd7 6.O-O O-O 7.e5 dxe5 8.dxe5 Ng4 9.e6 Nde5 10.Qxd8 Rxd8 11.Nxe5 Nxe5  1-0'],
 ['1.b5 d6 2.d4 Nf6 3.Nc3 g6 4.Nf3 Bg7 5.Be2 Nbd7 6.O-O O-O 7.e5 dxe5 8.dxe5 Ng4 9.e6 Nde5 10.Qxd8 Rxd8 11.Nxe5 Nxe5 12.Nb5  1/2-1/2']]`

Comment: Oh, thanks for pointing it out. An extra space is supposed to be added to the original string. I have edited the answer, you can check it now!